# "ERROR: missing required packages from profile myprofile" when building a simple cd

Tags: reprepro, simple-cdd, debian-cd

I'm using simple-cdd to create a Debian cd with only the packages I need for a re/installation of my system, but I'm facing some difficulties, namely, of the list of packages that I want to be installed on the CD, and therefore installed on the system, there are some that are not present at the time debian-cd is called by simple-cdd. I've managed to isolate the issue in reprepro not solving the dependencies in a sensible manner.

For example, I have set terminator package to be installed on the cd using the myprofile.packages file, it is missing at the time debian-cd is called as can be seen on the build-debian-cd.log:

```
stdout: Finished: 841 packages placed
stdout: purging /home/braiam/laptop-cdd/tmp/extras
stdout: simple-cdd: extra files for simple-cdd
stdout: ERROR: missing required packages from profile list:  network-manager-gnome terminator xfce4-appfinder xfce4-battery-plugin xfce4-panel xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfwm4
```

sort_deps.amd64.log reports the following about terminator package:

```
  Dependency tree of `terminator' ...
    Depends: gconf2
    Depends: python-dbus
    Depends: python-gobject
    Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.14.0)
    Depends: python-vte
    Depends: python <virt>
    Recommends: python-gnome2 <virt>
    Recommends: python-keybinder <virt>
    Recommends: python-notify <virt>
    Recommends: xdg-utils
Looking at list, line "terminator"
+ Trying to add terminator...
    terminator Dep: gconf2  soft_depend 0
    gconf2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    gconf2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      gconf2 not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    gconf2 Dep: gconf-service (= 3.2.6-4)  soft_depend 0
      gconf-service is included already, acceptable version 3.2.6-4
    gconf2 Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    gconf2 Dep: libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5)  soft_depend 0
      libgconf-2-4 is included already, acceptable version 3.2.6-4
    gconf2 Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    gconf2 Dep: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4)  soft_depend 0
      libxml2 is included already, acceptable version 2.9.4+dfsg1-2.1
    gconf2 Dep: (OR default-dbus-session-bus dbus-session-bus ) soft_depend 0
    default-dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    default-dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      default-dbus-session-bus not already installed
    dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    default-dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      default-dbus-session-bus not already installed
    dbus-session-bus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      dbus-session-bus not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
  gconf2 failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    gconf2 Dep: psmisc  soft_depend 0
    psmisc not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    psmisc not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      psmisc not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    psmisc Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    psmisc Dep: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)  soft_depend 0
      libselinux1 is included already, acceptable version 2.6-3
    psmisc Dep: libtinfo5 (>= 6)  soft_depend 0
      libtinfo5 is included already, acceptable version 6.0+20160917-1
  gconf2 failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    gconf2 Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
  terminator failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    terminator Dep: python-dbus  soft_depend 0
    python-dbus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-dbus not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-dbus not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-dbus Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-dbus Dep: python (>= 2.7~)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-dbus Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-dbus Dep: libc6 (>= 2.4)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-dbus Dep: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14)  soft_depend 0
      libdbus-1-3 is included already, acceptable version 1.10.12-1
    python-dbus Dep: libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78)  soft_depend 0
      libdbus-glib-1-2 is included already, acceptable version 0.108-1
    python-dbus Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
  terminator failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    terminator Dep: python-gobject  soft_depend 0
    python-gobject not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-gobject not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-gobject not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-gobject Dep: python-gi (>= 3.22.0-1)  soft_depend 0
    python-gi not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-gi not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-gi (>= 3.22.0-1) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-gi Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gi Dep: python (>= 2.7~)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gi Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gi Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gi Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-gi Dep: libffi6 (>= 3.0.4)  soft_depend 0
      libffi6 is included already, acceptable version 3.2.1-6
    python-gi Dep: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.44.0)  soft_depend 0
    libgirepository-1.0-1 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    libgirepository-1.0-1 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.44.0) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    libgirepository-1.0-1 Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    libgirepository-1.0-1 Dep: libffi6 (>= 3.0.4)  soft_depend 0
      libffi6 is included already, acceptable version 3.2.1-6
    libgirepository-1.0-1 Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.50.0)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    python-gi Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    python-gi Dep: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.39.0)  soft_depend 0
    gir1.2-glib-2.0 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    gir1.2-glib-2.0 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.39.0) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    gir1.2-glib-2.0 Dep: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.45.4)  soft_depend 0
    libgirepository-1.0-1 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    libgirepository-1.0-1 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    OR relationship already satisfied by parent libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.45.4)
    gir1.2-glib-2.0 Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.50.0)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    python-gobject Dep: python-gobject-2  soft_depend 0
    python-gobject-2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-gobject-2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-gobject-2 not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-gobject-2 Dep: python (>= 2.7)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gobject-2 Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gobject-2 Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gobject-2 Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-gobject-2 Dep: libffi6 (>= 3.0.4)  soft_depend 0
      libffi6 is included already, acceptable version 3.2.1-6
    python-gobject-2 Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
  terminator failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    terminator Dep: python-gtk2 (>= 2.14.0)  soft_depend 0
    python-gtk2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-gtk2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-gtk2 (>= 2.14.0) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-gtk2 Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gtk2 Dep: python (>= 2.7)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gtk2 Dep: python-numpy (>= 1:1.10.0~b1)  soft_depend 0
    python-numpy not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-numpy not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-numpy (>= 1:1.10.0~b1) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-numpy Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-numpy Dep: python (>= 2.7~)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-numpy Dep: python2.7  soft_depend 0
      python2.7 is included already, acceptable version 2.7.12-7
    python-numpy Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-numpy Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-numpy Dep: (OR libblas3 libblas3 ) soft_depend 0
      libblas3 is included already, acceptable version 3.6.1-2
    python-numpy Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-numpy Dep: (OR liblapack3 liblapack3 ) soft_depend 0
      liblapack3 is included already, acceptable version 3.6.1-2
    python-gtk2 Dep: python-numpy  soft_depend 0
    python-numpy not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-numpy not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    OR relationship already satisfied by parent python-numpy
    python-gtk2 Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gtk2 Dep: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4)  soft_depend 0
      libatk1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.22.0-1
    python-gtk2 Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-gtk2 Dep: libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4)  soft_depend 0
      libcairo2 is included already, acceptable version 1.14.6-1.1
    python-gtk2 Dep: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11)  soft_depend 0
      libfontconfig1 is included already, acceptable version 2.11.0-6.7
    python-gtk2 Dep: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1)  soft_depend 0
      libfreetype6 is included already, acceptable version 2.6.3-3+b1
    python-gtk2 Dep: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.36.0-1
    python-gtk2 Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    python-gtk2 Dep: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0)  soft_depend 0
      libgtk2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.24.31-1
    python-gtk2 Dep: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpango-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    python-gtk2 Dep: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.21.4)  soft_depend 0
      libpangocairo-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    python-gtk2 Dep: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.21.4)  soft_depend 0
      libpangoft2-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    python-gtk2 Dep: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1)  soft_depend 0
    python-cairo not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-cairo not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-cairo Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-cairo Dep: libcairo2 (>= 1.8.6)  soft_depend 0
      libcairo2 is included already, acceptable version 1.14.6-1.1
    python-cairo Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-cairo Dep: python (>= 2.7~)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-cairo Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-cairo Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-gtk2 Dep: python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3)  soft_depend 0
    python-gobject-2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-gobject-2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    OR relationship already satisfied by parent python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3)
  terminator failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    terminator Dep: python-vte  soft_depend 0
    python-vte not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-vte not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      python-vte not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-vte Dep: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4)  soft_depend 0
      libatk1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.22.0-1
    python-vte Dep: libc6 (>= 2.4)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    python-vte Dep: libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4)  soft_depend 0
      libcairo2 is included already, acceptable version 1.14.6-1.1
    python-vte Dep: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11)  soft_depend 0
      libfontconfig1 is included already, acceptable version 2.11.0-6.7
    python-vte Dep: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1)  soft_depend 0
      libfreetype6 is included already, acceptable version 2.6.3-3+b1
    python-vte Dep: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.36.0-1
    python-vte Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.26.0)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    python-vte Dep: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.20.0)  soft_depend 0
      libgtk2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.24.31-1
    python-vte Dep: libncurses5 (>= 6)  soft_depend 0
      libncurses5 is included already, acceptable version 6.0+20160917-1
    python-vte Dep: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpango-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    python-vte Dep: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpangocairo-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    python-vte Dep: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpangoft2-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    python-vte Dep: libtinfo5 (>= 6)  soft_depend 0
      libtinfo5 is included already, acceptable version 6.0+20160917-1
    python-vte Dep: libvte9 (>= 1:0.24.0)  soft_depend 0
    libvte9 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    libvte9 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      libvte9 (>= 1:0.24.0) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    libvte9 Dep: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4)  soft_depend 0
      libatk1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.22.0-1
    libvte9 Dep: libc6 (>= 2.14)  soft_depend 0
      libc6 is included already, acceptable version 2.24-7
    libvte9 Dep: libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4)  soft_depend 0
      libcairo2 is included already, acceptable version 1.14.6-1.1
    libvte9 Dep: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11)  soft_depend 0
      libfontconfig1 is included already, acceptable version 2.11.0-6.7
    libvte9 Dep: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1)  soft_depend 0
      libfreetype6 is included already, acceptable version 2.6.3-3+b1
    libvte9 Dep: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.36.0-1
    libvte9 Dep: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3)  soft_depend 0
      libglib2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.50.2-2
    libvte9 Dep: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0)  soft_depend 0
      libgtk2.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 2.24.31-1
    libvte9 Dep: libncurses5 (>= 6)  soft_depend 0
      libncurses5 is included already, acceptable version 6.0+20160917-1
    libvte9 Dep: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpango-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    libvte9 Dep: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpangocairo-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    libvte9 Dep: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0)  soft_depend 0
      libpangoft2-1.0-0 is included already, acceptable version 1.40.3-3
    libvte9 Dep: libtinfo5 (>= 6)  soft_depend 0
      libtinfo5 is included already, acceptable version 6.0+20160917-1
    libvte9 Dep: libx11-6  soft_depend 0
      libx11-6 is included already, acceptable version 2:1.6.3-1
    libvte9 Dep: libxext6  soft_depend 0
      libxext6 is included already, acceptable version 2:1.3.3-1
    libvte9 Dep: libvte-common (= 1:0.28.2-5)  soft_depend 0
    libvte-common not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    libvte-common not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
      libvte-common (= 1:0.28.2-5) not already installed
    OR relationship not already satisfied, looking at alternatives in order, check_backports 0
    python-vte Dep: libx11-6  soft_depend 0
      libx11-6 is included already, acceptable version 2:1.6.3-1
    python-vte Dep: libxext6  soft_depend 0
      libxext6 is included already, acceptable version 2:1.3.3-1
    python-vte Dep: python (>= 2.7)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-vte Dep: python (<< 2.8)  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
    python-vte Dep: python-gtk2  soft_depend 0
    python-gtk2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    python-gtk2 not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    OR relationship already satisfied by parent python-gtk2
    python-vte Dep: libvte-common (= 1:0.28.2-5)  soft_depend 0
    libvte-common not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    libvte-common not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
    OR relationship already satisfied by parent libvte-common (= 1:0.28.2-5)
  terminator failed, couldn't satisfy OR dep
    terminator Dep: python  soft_depend 0
      python is included already, acceptable version 2.7.11-2
Can't add terminator ... dependency problem.
```

As can be seen, the amount of packages to check is astounding... reaching unreasonable levels, to solve the dependencies of a *single* package. I've checked the [Troubleshooting section](https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD/Howto) of the how-to which states:

> If the build ends with an error such as:
>
> ```
> ERROR: missing required packages from profile MyProfile:  mplayer ...
> ```
>
> To find you why this package could not be added refer to:
>   `tmp/cd-build/$dist/sort_deps.$arch.log`
>
> You may need to explicitly add indirect dependencies. For example,
>   mplayer depends on mplayer-skin. Except there is no mplayer-skin
>   package. There is, however, an mplayer-skin-blue package that provides
>   mplayer-skin and satisfies the dependency. Same thing with some
>   updated packages that provide a number of older packages such as the
>   gtk2-engines-industrial package which is actually included in the
>   gtk2-engines package. **If you can determine which package you need, add
>   it to the *.downloads configuration file of packages** to be included on
>   the cd. (note: provides should be handled more-or-less correctly as of
>   simple-cdd 0.3.6) (note to the note: not so much. in one example,
>   xpdf-utils is no longer a real package. It is a transitional package
>   to poppler-utils. In upgrading the installer from lenny to squeeze,
>   this kept holding me back until I explicitly added all the second
>   level depends and the package causing the problem finally popped up in
>   the error message. **So to troubleshoot this, you need to start adding
>   all the packages apt adds automatically to the *.packages files until
>   you find a package that depends upon a transitional package.**)
>
> If simple-cdd does not handle the dependencies of a self build package
>   correctly, check it with lintian first. It took me two days to figure
>   out one of my packages which worked seamlessly with dpkg/apt/reprepro
>   had a mis-formatted header.

Apparently, I should be able to solve it by identifying the packages I need and add it to the .downloads file, but:

1. I'm unsure what's the criteria.
2. I tried the shotgun approach, adding all the packages that couldn't be found. That didn't solve the original problem and brought others.
3. It claims that some problems are due mis-formatted headers, so I should use lintian first, however these packages are installed from Debian's mirror, which normally don't have these kind of problems, but either way I don't know how to confirm it.
4. Removing the packages allows the CD to be built, but trying a higher dependency doesn't help. I changed those packages for task-xfce-desktop with more or less the same results.

Comment: I think you need to stop trying to use `simple-cdd` and try to find a tool that will do dependency resolution for you instead.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel what? simple-cdd doesn't try to resolve dependencies, reprepro does. Did you read the question?

Comment: Better to put your simple-cdd config file here. Also better to mention your mirrors and components clearly in that config.